# How to express interest in future intern opportunities even though accepting a competitors offer?

Tags: interviewing, internship, job-acceptance

Before jumping to "Duplicate" as found here:

> [What is the best way to deny a job offer and leave the door open for the near future?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/64310/what-is-the-best-way-to-deny-a-job-offer-and-leave-the-door-open-for-the-near-fu)

I really thought this was an appropriate question given my circumstances. I have recently accepted an intern position with my first choice company. Key point here is that this internship is clearly stated to be **temporary** only.

Earlier this week I had a phone-screen interview with another small company that seemed really enthusiastic to bring me in for a face to face interview. Of course I must halt this interview process, but I am actually quite interested in the possibility of either applying to this job after graduation (in 2 years) or interning with them next summer. Of course I never explicitly received an offer, but should my "Thanks for your consideration, but I'd like to withdraw my application" email look any different than a "standard" no-nonsense withdrawal email?

Comment: Question in title and body don't match. Since the former isn't very useful I'd suggest editing to focus here on how you should word this, since that's presumably what you're mainly asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be wise to indicate that while you can not proceed with the interview process, that you still are interested in the company. Since you stated that it is a small company, the hiring manager might remember you. You don't have to provide a reason for no longer seeking employment.

Comment: Ok, I was not sure how to go about that email. Your response has provided a good bit of clarity. Being a student, the proper etiquette for how to handle many of these situations is still foreign.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I have come across situation while applying for more than one startups. Startups are very small, and they require man-power so they do jump into getting the best talent in. But nevertheless, they also know that they can't hire **all**.

Coming to your situation, you may just send an email stating few pointer

- Thank you for your time
- Thanks your for your consideration
- Regret to inform that I have already accepted another job offer OR to be positive I am not seeking any employment for this summer.
- Looking forward to work at XYZ company in near future.

The above points will reflect your formality and being upfront with the situation. So that they don't rely on you anymore.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed a smaller company, actually primarily made up of alum's from my school. Would this be an appropriate response? 
Hello Mr.___, 
Thank you very much for considering me, and taking the time to speak with me about the intern position with ___.
However, after very careful consideration, I regret to inform that I have accepted another offer and therefore would like to withdraw my application for the internship position with ____. I sincerely appreciate your time to speak with me and I look forward to potential future> opportunities with ____.

Comment: @Matt Nice response. Don't use `very` it means nothing, it makes your response informal. Rest all looks good. Best Of Luck! :) Don't forget to accept and approve the answer if that fits ur `required answer`

Answer (score 0):

The emotional impact of a candidate turning down an internship opportunity can be any where from being turned down for a free sample in mall cafeteria (none) to being turned down for prom (a lot).

But remember that you are interviewing the company as much as they are interviewing you. It's a two-way street. Consider whether you'd want to work for a company that is petty, refuses to acknowledge or understand your situation and holds small slights against you in the future. If this company will refuse to consider you in the future because you had a better opportunity, is that really a bad thing?